# Generate a bunch of random ngons that are perfectly packed

Tags: javascript, geometry, shapes

The problem here is I don't really know the right question to ask, but essentially I want to generate a pattern of ngons that all fit perfectly together, kinda like the picture.

[image]

Is there an algorithm or anything that can do this?

FYI I'm attempting this in JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm you want is a [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). The essential description of the algorithm is such:

1. Generate a list of random points on a plane (or get the points as input from somewhere).
2. Create a geometric map of n-gons that represent all the space in the plane closest to each point.

The resulting graph will look something like this (stylized and colored):

[image]

The look and shape of the n-gons depend on the spacing of the points. You can play with different point distributions or generation methods to get a Voronoi Diagram with particular characteristics. You can also play with the n-gons themselves, for example you can treat the boundaries as fuzzy approximations, blending or leaving gaps between adjacent n-gons:

[image]

There are a ton of cool things you can do with a Voronoi Diagram, and pretty much every programming language has libraries that can compute one very quickly. For example, one of the interactive examples for Paper.js is a [dynamically generated Voronoi Diagram where one of the points is the location of the cursor](http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/). Here's another example where someone uses Voronoi Diagrams as one of the steps for [procedural terrain generation](https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/mapgen2/). Yet another example is a [Voronoi Diagram using the locations of all the airports in the world](https://observablehq.com/@d3/world-airports-voronoi?collection=@d3/d3-delaunay), which you could use to find the closest airport to any location on the planet.

One such library in Javascript is [d3-voronoi](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi), though like I said, there are quite a few libraries out there, not to mention a gazillion tutorial articles on how to implement it yourself should you decide to go that route.